# Problem with getting tweet_fields from Twitter API 2.0 using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I have a similar problem as in this question ([Problem with getting user.fields from Twitter API 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615958/problem-with-getting-user-fields-from-twitter-api-2-0/70366920#70366920))
but I am using Tweepy. When making the request with tweet_fields, the response is only giving me the default values. In another fuction where I use user_fields it works perfectly.
I followed this guide, specifically number 17 (https://dev.to/twitterdev/a-comprehensive-guide-for-using-the-twitter-api-v2-using-tweepy-in-python-15d9)

My function looks like this:

```
def get_user_tweets():
    client = get_client()
    tweets = client.get_users_tweets(id=get_user_id(), max_results=5)
    ids = []
    for tweet in tweets.data:
        ids.append(str(tweet.id))

    tweets_info = client.get_tweets(ids=ids, tweet_fields=["public_metrics"])
    print(tweets_info)
```

This is my response (with the last tweets from elonmusk) also there is no error code or anything else

```
Response(data=[<Tweet id=1471419792770973699 text=@WholeMarsBlog I came to the US with no money &amp; graduated with over $100k in debt, despite scholarships &amp; working 2 jobs while at school>, <Tweet id=1471399837753135108 text=@TeslaOwnersEBay @PPathole @ScottAdamsSays @johniadarola @SenWarren It’s complicated, but hopefully out next quarter, along with Witcher. Lot of internal debate as to whether we should be putting effort towards generalized gaming emulation vs making individual games work well.>, <Tweet id=1471393851843792896 text=@PPathole @ScottAdamsSays @johniadarola @SenWarren Yeah!>, <Tweet id=1471338213549744130 text=link>, <Tweet id=1471325148435394566 text=@24_7TeslaNews @Tesla ❤️>], includes={}, errors=[], meta={})
```

Comment: Pay attention to indentation (4 spaces after method-declaration). What does it print? Or is there any error on console - share this, please.

Comment: What happens if you follow the question's answer: add argument [`expansions = ['author_id']`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/client.html?highlight=return+Tweets#expansions-parameter) to call of `get_tweets` ?

Comment: thank you i edited my question. If I add expansions=["author_id"] it just gives me Information about the user but still not the public metrics.

Answer (score 8):

I found this link: https://giters.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1670. According to it,

> Response is a namedtuple. Here, within its data field, is a single Tweet object.

> The string representation of a Tweet object will only ever include its ID and text. This was an intentional design choice, to reduce the excess of information that could be displayed when printing all the data as the string representation, as with models.Status. The ID and text are the only default / guaranteed fields, so the string representation remains consistent and unique, while still being concise. This design is used throughout the API v2 models.

> To access the data of the Tweet object, you can use attributes or keys (like a dictionary) to access each field.
> If you want all the data as a dictionary, you can use the data attribute/key.

In that case, to access public metrics, you could maybe try doing this instead:

```
tweets_info = client.get_tweets(ids=ids, tweet_fields=["public_metrics"])
for tweet in tweets_info.data:
    print(tweet["id"])
    print(tweet["public_metrics"])
```

Comment: Thanks ! This helped  :)